# Run MochaJS before start node server automated

Tags: node.js, express, jenkins, mocha.js

I am new to Mocha.js, but I did some test cases and I would like to run these tests before my server starts automatically.

For example:
npm start
Then all Mocha's tests run and if it passes the server starts, if not the server stops.

I am using Jenkins for automated deploy

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your server?

If so, you should handle your server lifecycle using **before** and **after** functions like this:

```
var server = require('../my/lib/server');

describe('My server test suite', function () {
  before(function () {
    server.listen(8080);
  });

  it('should do my test', function(done){
    //my test
  });

  after(function () {
    server.close();
  });
});
```

Place your mocha execution in the test task from npm's `package.json`, for example this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --globals '*'"
}
```

Then you can run `npm install && npm test` in your **server-test** job under **Execute shell** build step.

Then if you want to deploy that tested version you should:

- Create another job (ex: **server-deploy**).
- Install and use [Parametrized Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) inside your **server-test** job to trigger/call builds on other projects as a post-build step.
- Add [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) npm module on your project
- On the **server-deploy** job, use forever + dontKillMe flag to keep the process running after the Jenkins job has completed like this:

`BUILD_ID=dontKillMe forever start myserver.js`

PS: the explanation for using BUILD_ID=dontKillme is [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller).

Comment: Could you not just use prestart in package.json? Genuinely curious as to how this is better?